# MSN API for Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to know whether if there is any Objective-C MSN API. I have searched for a while and could not really find one.

And if not could somebody tell some good place to look to start the protocol from scratch. Some points on how to start with.

I found this site mentioning details about the protocol. But still not sure how to start with.

http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/index.php

Thank you and Kind Regards,

Tharindu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be out of luck.  MSN is proprietary so APIS are going to be thin on the ground and those that exist will be reverse engineered.

Having said that, Pidgin is an open source IM client that supports MSN.  You could use its core library ([libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Libpurple)) which is written in C and hence compatible with Objective-C.